# Screen not loading after login is authenticated in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created a route to the home screen which should be displayed after login is successful. However, my circular bar just keeps moving (indicating isLoading stage) and the home screen does not show up in the simulator.

I am aware that the login is successful since my response variable does print the information in the console that it accesses after login.

On pressing the login the button 2 main issues are displayed:
1) Exception thrown while handling a gesture
2) Unhandled Exception: Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null

I am unable to solve this these 2 issues. Any help would be great.
Thanks in advance!

There is no compilation error. The following are the main issues shown after pressing the login button (complete stack tree and message posted later in the question):

```
flutter: The following ArgumentError was thrown while handling a       gesture:
flutter: Invalid argument (onError): Error handler must accept one     Object or one Object and a StackTrace as
flutter: arguments, and return a a valid result: Closure: (Exception) => void

Unhandled Exception: Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null
```

The console message posted later refers to 3 files. I have posted important code of the files below.

File: login_screen.dart

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new LoginScreenState();
  }
}

class LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen>
    implements LoginScreenContract, AuthStateListener {
  BuildContext _ctx;

  bool _isLoading = false;
  final formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  String _password, _username;

  LoginScreenPresenter _presenter;

  LoginScreenState() {
    _presenter = new LoginScreenPresenter(this);
     var authStateProvider = new AuthStateProvider();
    authStateProvider.subscribe(this);
  }

  void _submit() {
    final form = formKey.currentState;

    if (form.validate()) {
      setState(() => _isLoading = true);
      form.save();
      _presenter.doLogin(_username, _password);
    }
  }

  void _showSnackBar(String text) {
    scaffoldKey.currentState
        .showSnackBar(new SnackBar(content: new Text(text)));
  }

  @override
  onAuthStateChanged(AuthState state) {

    if(state == AuthState.LOGGED_IN)
      Navigator.of(_ctx).pushReplacementNamed("/home");
  }

  @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _ctx = context;
    ....(UI for login screen)
  @override
  void onLoginError(String errorTxt) {
    _showSnackBar(errorTxt);
    setState(() => _isLoading = false);
  }

   @override
   void onLoginSuccess(User user) async {
   HomeScreen()));
    _showSnackBar(user.toString());
    setState(() => _isLoading = false);
    var db = new DatabaseHelper();
    await db.saveUser(user);
    var authStateProvider = new AuthStateProvider();
    HomeScreen()));
    authStateProvider.notify(AuthState.LOGGED_IN);
    onAuthStateChanged(AuthState.LOGGED_IN);
  }
}
```

File: login_screen_presenter.dart

```
import 'package:better_login/rest_ds.dart';
import 'package:better_login/user.dart';

abstract class LoginScreenContract {
  void onLoginSuccess(User user);
  void onLoginError(String errorTxt);
}

 class LoginScreenPresenter {
  LoginScreenContract _view;
  RestDatasource api = new RestDatasource();
  LoginScreenPresenter(this._view);

  doLogin(String username, String password) {
    api.login(username, password).then((User user) {
      _view.onLoginSuccess(user);
     }).catchError((Exception error) =>
        _view.onLoginError(error.toString()));
  }
}
```

File: rest_ds.dart

```
 static final LOGIN_URL = "https://legacy-  api.example.com/v1/auth/login";


   Future<User> login(String username, String password) {
     return _netUtil.post(LOGIN_URL, body: {
       "username": username,
       "password": password
    }).then((dynamic res) {
      print(res.toString());
       if(res["error"]){ throw new Exception(res["error_msg"]);}
       return new User.map(res["user"]);
    });
  }
```

}

This is the complete info displayed in the console:

```
flutter: The following ArgumentError was thrown while handling a gesture:
flutter: Invalid argument (onError): Error handler must accept one Object or one Object and a StackTrace as
flutter: arguments, and return a a valid result: Closure: (Exception) => void
flutter:
flutter: When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
flutter: #2      LoginScreenPresenter.doLogin   (package:better_login/login_screen_presenter.dart:17:8)
flutter: #3      LoginScreenState._submit (package:better_login/login_screen.dart:41:18)
flutter: #4      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:511:14)
flutter: #5      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:566:30)
flutter: #6      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:166:24)
flutter: #7      TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:240:9)
flutter: #8      TapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:177:9)
flutter: #9      PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:436:9)
flutter: #10     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:73:12)
flutter: #11     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:101:11)
flutter: #12        _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:221:19)
flutter: #13     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:199:22)
flutter: #14     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:156:7)
flutter: #15     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:102:7)
flutter: #16     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:86:7)
flutter: #20     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:233:10)
flutter: #21     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:154:5)
flutter: (elided 5 frames from package dart:async)
flutter:
flutter: Handler: onTap
flutter: Recognizer:
flutter:   TapGestureRecognizer#398b8(debugOwner: GestureDetector,   state: possible, won arena, finalPosition:
flutter:   Offset(194.0, 504.0), sent tap down)
flutter: ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: {status: success, message: Authentication Success,   executionTime: 0.052, data: {token:    U2FsdGVkX19ZQS5wQXRYWTkh2o4PyrtmhS4kELJO0WsEBDbn30G9Oig/13fzHzqZ,   custKey: anb2mNXFERnJ4IQW....(rest is info got on login)
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: Failed   assertion:  boolean expression must not be null
#0      RestDatasource.login.<anonymous closure>   (package:better_login/rest_ds.dart:21:13)
#1      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#2      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#3      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:126:18)
#4      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:639:45)
#5      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:668:32)
#6      Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:473:7)
#7      _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
#8      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:28:18)
#9      _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:294:13)
#10     _withClient (package:http/http.dart)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     post (package:http/http.dart:69:5)
#12     NetworkUtil.post (package:better_login/network_util.dart<…>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues in your code:

- `catchError` param is not of type `Exception` is of type `Object`. You can use the second param of `catchError`, `test` to filter errors received. This is the cause of the crash report trace  `The following ArgumentError was thrown while handling a gestur`.
- the main cause of the crash is here `if(res["error"]){ throw new Exception(res["error_msg"]);}`, because the `res["error"]` is probably null. To fix it change it to `if(res["error"] != null) ....`.

Refactoring points:

- you don't need to save the build context in a `_ctx` variable, any subclass of `State` has access to it's main `context` via `context` property.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! The above steps resolve previous issues. But the home screen still doesn't load and I am facing a NoSuchMethodError. The following message pops up on the simulator: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null, Receiver: null, Tried calling: []("username"). How can I solve this issue?

Comment: @SarangRastogi I think your issue is caused by the json handling. I think the problem is here ```User.map(res["user"]```.